# Select column dynamically based on value from another column in R

Tags: r, data.table

How do I use column in data table as variable name to fetch values from other columns based on the said column.

```
library(data.table)
a = c(2,3,5)
b = c(5,7,7)
c = c(1,2,3)
x = c ('a','b','c')
dt <- data.table(a,b,c,x)

> dt
   a b c x
1: 2 5 1 a
2: 3 7 2 b
3: 5 7 3 c
```

output I desire column y which is based on values of column x which contains the column names of values to be fetched.

```
dt
   a b c x y
1: 2 5 1 a 2
2: 3 7 2 b 7
3: 5 7 3 c 3
```

I tried

```
dt[,get(x)]

dt[,match(x,colnames(dt))]
```

Comment: use the `dt[, y := dt[, get(x), 1:nrow(dt)]$V1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looping through the sequence of rows, extract the value with `get` and assign it to create 'y'

```
dt[, y := .SD[, get(x), seq_len(.N)]$V1]
dt
#   a b c x y
#1: 2 5 1 a 2
#2: 3 7 2 b 7
#3: 5 7 3 c 3
```

Comment: Should be more efficient to do this by=x than by row, I guess. (Fwiw, searching for a dupe.)

Comment: Just one more help. How to insert this y column at beggining of frame?

Comment: @OmerFarooq  After the assignment `setcolorder(dt, c("y", setdiff(names(dt), "y")))`

Comment: @akrun Just `setcolorder(dt, 'y')` should suffice in the latest version (I think since v1.11.0).